# How to slide out and slide in two divs alternately in single line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to do function to sliding new added content, using jQuery slide effect but I can't apply any solutions to put two divs in a single line. How to fix code below to slide from left to the right side by side? Maybe this code is completely to rebuild?

jsFiddle:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xuKz/2/)

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#hello").html("Hello");
    $('#edit').toggle(function() {
        var newhtml = '<input type="text" id="hello_input" value="" />';
        slideNewContent(newhtml);
    }, function() {
        var newhtml = $("#hello_input").val();
        slideNewContent(newhtml);
    });
});

function slideNewContent(c) {
    $("#slideOut").empty();
    $("#slideIn").children().clone().appendTo("#slideOut");
    $("#slideIn").find("#hello").html(c);
    var slideOut = $("#slideOut");
    var slideIn = $("#slideIn");
    slideOutIn(slideOut, slideIn);
}

function slideOutIn(outElement, inElement) {
    var hideoptions = { "direction": "right", "mode": "hide" };
    var showoptions = { "direction": "left", "mode": "show" };
    $(outElement).effect("slide", hideoptions, 1000);
    $(inElement).effect("slide", showoptions, 1000);
}
```

​HTML:

```
<div class="span3">
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="slideIn" class="content">
            <span>       
                <span id="hello"></span>
                <button class="btn btn-mini" id="edit">Edit</button>
            </span>           
        </div>
        <div id="slideOut" class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
  /*float:left;*/
    display: inline-block;
}
#slideIn {
   width: 270px;
  /*display: inline;*/
}
#slideOut {
    width: 270px;
  /*display: inline;*/
}
#hello_input {
  width:160px;
}
```

Comment: Make the `.content` `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

Edit to this

```
$(outElement).effect("slide", hideoptions, 0);
    $(inElement).effect("slide", showoptions, 0);
```